# Avoid Doctrine to return all entities

Tags: object, symfony, doctrine, entity

Using Symfony2 / doctrine2, while we use the find() function to get a specific object based on the entity selected if there are relations (like OneToMany), Doctrine return all other object.

For example :

```
$em = $this->get(
         'doctrine.orm.entity_manager', 
          $request->getSession()->get('entity_manager')
);
$product = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Product')->find($id);
```

The result on $product will be the Product object + other linked objects like (Store, Category, ...etc.)

How can we control doctrine to determinate which object we need to be returned.

I can use Querybuilder, but i am looking if there are any function all determinate.

Answer (score 5):

> Doctrine return all other object

This is not how it works, at least by default.

Doctrine uses what is called [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading).
From the official documentation, you have the following example:

```
<?php
/** @Entity */
class Article
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    private $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $headline;

    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User") */
    private $author;

    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="article") */
    private $comments;

    public function __construct {
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getAuthor() { return $this->author; }
    public function getComments() { return $this->comments; }
}

$article = $em->find('Article', 1);
```

And the following explanation:

> Instead of passing you back a real Author instance and a collection of
>   comments Doctrine will create proxy instances for you. Only if you
>   access these proxies for the first time they will go through the
>   EntityManager and load their state from the database.

Reference: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#entity-object-graph-traversal

More information about the topic: http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine-lazy-loading.html

Comment: hehe we had the same idea here :)

Answer (score 3):

You can configure [extra lazy associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html) to avoid loading of relations in general.

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="CmsUser", mappedBy="groups", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
 */
protected $property;
```