# Will Doctrine delete the object using remove() without calling flush()?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

In my symfony2 application I've been running into errors of the type:

`E_ERROR: Allowed memory size of * bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)`

That said, I'm in the process of refactoring my code, but the only way I've found on how to delete doctrine objects is by calling the method `remove()`.

According to Symfony's documentation:

the method `remove()` notifies Doctrine that you want to DELETE a row from your database, but doctrine won't do anything until you call `flush()`

My question is...

Can I call `remove()` in the same fashion I would use `unset` to remove an object from memory? as long as I don't call `flush()`?

If not, what's the best way to "unset" objects using the "Symfony way" to do things ?

Comment: Wait what now? Objects? Symfon? Doctrine? Unset? "Unset"? The PHP way honestly? Raise the memory limit for that operation.

Comment: I hope it was as easy as raising the memory limit. The memory limit has been raised twice already.

Comment: Well so it did work then right? Why not reaise it a third and fourth time? What has been proven working should be deemed good.

Comment: Why would you unset object when doctrine uses lazy loading? You probably load too much information in the first place. Have you a sample code to show where you have this error?

Comment: Is that your approach to fix things? Make a temporary patch until it breaks again? then apply the patch again? 
Raising the memory limit will affect the concurrency too, the solution is writing better code and that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @cheesemacfly at first it was happening in a page that stores too many stuff into sessions, I changed that and instead of using sessions I started to use temporary tables in MySQL, and creating queues so that those processes are run in the background through cron jobs. Now the issue is happening at different places throughout the application. I believe that by posting sample code this question will be too localized.

Comment: My point being, if you have a list of entities and you get the error you mentioned, then this list is probably loading too much information (and/or objects). But with no context, it is hard to say...Are you using the `findAll()` a lot? Do you have any query linking a lot of objects together?

Comment: @cheesemacfly I'm not using `findAll()` a lot,  but I do have some queries that link a lot of objects together. I thought it would be better to use raw SQL for that, but I may be wrong

Comment: Well, it depends on your usage of those objects. For example, if you don't necessarily use the joined object, you might want to write your code based on [Doctrine's lazy loading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17955314/1443490). If you do use all the objects you are already loading, I am afraid that you won't have much way to solve this issue but using @hakre's solution...

Comment: @AlanChavez: Sure, I'm totally with you. Problem with writing better code is you need to understand what you do. So far I only see you asking. I'd say get into the know first otherwise - as also this stream of comments perhaps indicates - things tend to become like guessing. So for debugging, you need to find out first what exactly is consuming the memory.

Comment: I have an import process that quickly hits memory limits.  I use $entityManager->clear();  to basically reset doctrine and make your entities available for garbage collection.  For my purposes it works great.  Your mileage might very.  And if you happen to be loading and modifying existing entities then implementing the change notification tracking policy can make a big difference as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is telling doctrine to stop referencing these objects that php can free memory. You probably do not want to remove the database rows because php is running out of memory ...

[Read how to detach entities](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities) and [what are the different entities states](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/architecture.html#entity-states) and what it means.